# Creating multiple objects to then use in tkinter?

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter

I am wondering if it is even possible to do this, I have a text file with about 20 letters, and for each letter a rectangle (all the same size) needs to be 'drawn' or shown. And for each letter, they have their own colour. Their properties would be height width and colour (height and width both a constant value) I plan to use tkinter to 'draw' this because its just simpler for me. But I'm wondering if it might be easier to create instances of a class so each letter in the text file becomes an object with its own height colour and width. Would this make it easier for me to create shapes for in tkinter? If so how would I implement making an object for every item in the text file?

I'm so sorry if I didnt make a lot of sense

Edit: Here is my sad attempt at trying to code for this..
Sequencedfile1 = a text file one letter on each line

```
class Sequence:

def __init__(self, width, height, base):
    self.width = 75
    self.height = 100
    self.base = base


def create_base_objects(self, width, height, base):
    f = open("sequencedfile1.txt", "r+")
    with open('sequencedfile1.txt', 'r') as f:
        for item in f:
            for x in range(0, 1):
                 str(object,x) = Sequence(75, 100, item)
```

Comment: Yes, this can be an ideal use of objects. Each instance has the same properties, but the values of those properties could be entirely different to each other.

Comment: Of course it can.  But you need to provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks! Ive edited the post and added my attempt at coding it

Comment: What is `str(object,x) = ...` supposed to do? I think you might just want a list comprehension: `objects = [Sequence(75, 100, item) for item in f]`. Also, don't open the file twice, remove the `f = ...` above `with`

Comment: I wasnt sure how to implement this but in my head I wanted it so each object could be called object1, object2 etc

Comment: Oh, _that_. Don't do that. Use a list, as shown above, then use `objects[0]`, `objects[1]`, etc.

Comment: Also note that `item` may still include the `\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a detailed explanation:
I created a text file as 'try.txt' and wrote hello on it as the sample text.

**Imports required:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import random
import threading
```

**The Main Body:**
the class blocks will create an object with colour and text given by the user while calling.The the place function will pack "(can be changed to place if required)" the object created on the tkinter window which is given as the parameter by the user (root).

The function create block will read every letter inside the file and will create an object of that letter with any random colour chosen by the computer in random.choice.
Here time.sleep() is used to give a one second delay to give this thing an animated look.

```
class blocks:
    def __init__(self,colour,text):
        self.colour=colour
        self.width=5
        self.height=5
        self.text=text

    def place(self,root):
        self.name=tk.Label(root,text=self.text,width=self.width,height=self.height,bg=self.colour)
        self.name.pack()

def create_blocks():
    f=open('try.txt','r')
    r=f.read()
    for i in r:
        col=random.choice(['red','blue','green','yellow','pink'])
        i=blocks(col,i)
        i.place(window)
        time.sleep(1)
```

**Making the window for tkinter:**
The main tkinter window is created and when the button is pressed a separate thread will start which will call/start the create_blocks function.

```
window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry('400x400')
boo=tk.Button(text='TRY',command=threading.Thread(target=create_blocks).start).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

[image: This is how it looks]

Comment: Could you actually help me with a scope problem with this code? @DeathMaster

Comment: I didnt got what u asking @el1101 ,actually i am also new to tkinter and stackoverflow